# Using generalized method of moments (GMM) with partially overlapping expectational errors

Tags: generalized-moments

I use GMM to estimate the log-linear Euler equation (using Stata). But I have autocorrelated error terms of the MA(q) form because of partially overlapping expectational errors. I'm a bit confused by this... Should I take it into account only when choosing instruments or am I mistaken and something else should be done?

Thank you!